# number of setbits in a number and a game based on setbits

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bit-shift, bitset, game-theory

I was trying this problem on bits manipulation came through this one:

Beauty of a number is the number of set bits in that number. A and B start playing a game where there is number N written on the board,the player whose turn is to move goes to the board and writes a new number N-K where k<=N and beauty of K is 1.It is also important that beauty of N-K must be equal to beauty of N. 
Last player to successfully complete his move wins the game.

They both play the game optimally.

P.S. i am not looking for a code here.I want to know how to approach this?

Comment: Game search tree http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_tree and binary permutations http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation

Comment: Can you provide the link to the problem. I am interested to solve this one if it was on a programming site. Thank you.

Comment: no this problem was not on any programming site.actually this is an interview question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a typical game theory problem. Players play optimally means that any player will make the move such that it maximizes it chance of winning (taking into account that when player 2 gets a chance he will also be willing to do the same).

Now in this case let us see what are the moves allowed:

As required the beauty of a number should remain same and the `k` should have beauty `1` *i.e.* only 1 bit set(for ex. `00000100`)

For further illustration let us assume that we only have 8 bit number.

If you see closely, for beauty of `N` to remain same, the bit set in `k` is at the (one of the) index at which `N` has a `0` and `1` is at left adjacent to it. I will take an example:

Let us say `N` is `01010001`. now k can be `00100000`, `00001000`. If you see `N-k` the beauty remains same. After the operation, you will notice that `1` moves to right and hence `0` moves to left. For example when `N=01010001` and `k=00100000` `(N-k) = 00110001`.

Also the ending position of the game will be such that all `0's` are to the left and and all `1's` are to the right(`00000111`). You can count the number of moves possible given a number `N`. If it is odd then the player starting wins otherwise he loses.

Now to count the number of such moves is simple enumeration problem.

Comment: isn't `number of moves` equal to no. of `0's` to right of most significant set bit ?